# PHP fazer update com for

Tags: php, mysql

**ATUALIZADO**

Preciso fazer um update de uma tabelas com campos de inputs conforme abaixo:

```
  <table style="width: 100%;">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Item</th>
     <th>Código</th>
     <th>Produto</th>
     <th>Valor</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <?php while($dado_produto = $result_produtos->fetch_array()){ ?>
    <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td><?php echo $dado_produto['cod']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $dado_produto['descricao']; ?></td>
     <td><input type = "text" name="valor[<?php echo $dado_produto['cod']; ?>]"/>
     <input type = "hidden" name="linha[<?php echo $dado_produto['linha']; ?>]"/>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <?php } ?> 
   </tbody>
   </table>
   </div> 
   <input type="submit"/>
   </form>
```

ao enviar para o arquivo valor.php, está aparecendo o erro:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

o código segue abaixo:

```
if($stmt->prepare("UPDATE `produto` SET (`valor`='?' WHERE `codigo`='?' AND `linha` = '?'")) {  

    $stmt->bind_param('sii', $valor, $cod, $linha);

    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['novo_valor']);$i++){
        $valor = $POST['novo_valor'][$i];
        $cod = $_POST['cod'][$i];
        $linha = $_POST['linha'][$i];
        $stmt->execute();
    }


    $stmt->close();
}
```

a linha 35 é a

```
 if($stmt->prepare("UPDATE `produto` SET (`valor`='?' WHERE `codigo`='?' AND `linha` = '?'")) {
```

O erro se refere a que?

Comment: Como você está iniciando a variável `$stmt`? Você está tentando acessar um método em uma variável que não é um objeto.

Answer (score 4):

Faltou o `underline` e o `;` no final:

```
$valor = $_POST['novo_valor'][$i];
```

Comment: Obrigado :), agora aparece novo erro PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Comment: A sua váriavel `$stmt` esta recebendo uma instancia antes de chamar o procedimento `prepare()`? Porque no código que você postou acima não tem essa linha.

Answer (score 0):

É necessário confirmar se tem a inicialização correta do objeto `$stmt` que tem de vir do objeto que representa a ligação à base de dados:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($servidor, $utilizador, $password, $nomeBaseDados);
```

Depois o `if` passa a ser:

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `produto` SET `valor`='?' WHERE `codigo`='?' AND `linha` = '?'")) {
```

Porque o *prepare* tem de ser chamado sobre o objeto que representa a ligação e devolve o *prepared statement*, que vai depois ser utilizado dentro do `if`.

Comment: eu fiz conforme me indicou, mas agora não aparece nenhum erro, mas não muda nada no meu banco de dados

Comment: Agora estou a reparar que a própria consulta não está certa porque tem um `(` a mais em `SET(`